# ggplot put text and draw extra line on facet plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a facet plot with multiple subjects. There are 15 trials as the x-axis (4 in the example I made). How can I put the text 'shock' on the points of certain trials (i.e., 5 and 7) and at the same time draw a red line on the points (something like the plot below)? Or, alternatively, make the point 5 and 7 as different shapes.

[image]

```
ggplot (data=k, aes(x=trial,y=value))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  facet_wrap(~factor(subject,levels=c(paste0('subject',1:2))))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4:7))

k <- structure(list(subject = c("subject1", "subject2", "subject1", 
                           "subject2", "subject1", "subject2", "subject1", "subject2"), 
               value = c(0.878597435209789, 0.0176290115770756, 0.985258898204333, 
                         0.0347178797899928, 0.119612343633264, 0.0336586124505415, 
                         0.0145236522430737, 0.0326404660694124), trial = c(4L, 4L, 
                                                                            5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                        "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add include label as `'shock'` where `trial` is either 5 or 7 and include it in `shape` inside `geom_point`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

k %>%
  mutate(label = ifelse(trial %in% c(5, 7), 'shock', '')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=trial,y=value, label = label)) +
  geom_point(aes(shape = label, color = label)) +
  geom_line()+
  geom_text(vjust = -1) + 
  facet_wrap(~factor(subject,levels=c(paste0('subject',1:2))))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(4:7)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue')) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(color=FALSE, shape = FALSE)
```

[image]